# Change default date value while entering time

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula

Upon entering time value as ***12:45*** in a cell formatted as **dd/mm/yy hh:mm**, the following date value gets entered by default: **01/00/1900  12:45:00**.

I want it to enter **today's** date, i.e. ***the date of entry*** by default

I'm using MS Excel 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do it in one step like you're looking for. To do it in a couple of steps, first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + semicolon, which enters the current date. Then press space, followed by the time.

To enter the current time, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> + semicolon. So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + semicolon, followed by that gets you the current date and time.

Comment: Although not a one step process but thanks for the shortcut key. It definitely saves some time :)