# Current Month/Year instead of January 1900

Tags: excel, libreoffice-calc

I got range of cells with set formatting > "Date", and by default when I'm typing any number it is converted to date with day I've typed and January 1900.

How to change it so I would get always current month and year after typing just numbers of day ?

How to do this in LibreOffice Calc aswell ?

Comment: you can Change it to January 1904 by going to `Options -> Advanced -> when calculating this workbook` and check the box next to *Use 1904 date system*.... But that's as far as I got. Similar question from 2013, but also no real solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993664/change-default-date-value-while-entering-time

Comment: That is basically impossible to implement generally. A date representation is just a number formatting applied to a cell value. You might be able to solve your problem partly by adding an additional column that just contains a formula. Let us assume the column that contains your input is column A and cell C1 contains an offset to the official zero date. Then use in the B column a formula like =A1+$C$1 and fill the formula in the whole B column.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Excel.  This example uses the range from **A1** through **A10**  Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rint As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
    Set rint = Intersect(rng, Target)

    For Each r In rint
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            r.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), r.Value)
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Next r
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

The code takes your typed value and replaces it with the properly constructed date.  You can change the range to suite your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from @Gary's Student can be adapted for LibreOffice as follows.

```vb
Sub ContentChangedHandler(oChangedRange As Object)
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim oCheckingRange As Object
    Dim oIntersectRanges As Object
    Dim oIntersectRange As Object
    Dim oData()
    Dim oRow()
    Dim i%, j%, k%
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    oCheckingRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:A10").getRangeAddress()
    oIntersectRanges = oChangedRange.queryIntersection(oCheckingRange)
    For i = 0 to oIntersectRanges.getCount() - 1
        oIntersectRange = oIntersectRanges.getByIndex(i)
        oData() = oIntersectRange.getDataArray()
        For j = LBound(oData()) To UBound(oData())
            oRow() = oData(j)
            For k = LBound(oRow()) To UBound(oRow())
                oRow(k) = CLng(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), oRow(k)))
            Next
        Next
        oIntersectRange.setDataArray(oData())
    Next
End Sub
```

To set up the event, right-click on the sheet tab and choose `Sheet Events`.  Assign the `Content changed` event to the macro above.

Be sure to format the cells as dates by going to `Format -> Cells`, or else they will be displayed as ordinary numbers.